# How to dynamically add grouped _categories in Highcharts in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I want pass the XAxis Grouped categories dynamically from the code behind as showing in image
How can i do that need Help.
[image: Exaple Image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that currently, it is impossible to use this custom JS plugin in the Highcharts .NET wrapper because categories in the wrapper are defined as strings, not array.